# Which command allows me to read a pdf from stdin?

Tags: pdf, evince, okular

I am looking for a GUI program that opens a pdf from stdin.

For instance, if `pdf_stdin` is the command that opens my pdf from stdin, I'd like to use

- `ggp -d -r mail@mail.com encrypted.pdf.gpg -o - | pdf_stdin`
- `man -t arpwatch | pdf_stdin`

Comment: In general, it's unlikely, since PDFs are supposed to be read from the end, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11896942/2072269, and stdin from a pipe is not seekable, so once it reaches the end, unless it had the whole thing cached, it won't be able to display the rest of the PDF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) ([archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zathura)) is a minimalist document viewer (PDF/PS/Djvu/CB).  It can display documents from stdin.

```
cat foo.pdf | zathura -
```

The version on my system saves the pipe temporarily to /tmp, so the displayed document is seekable.  The temporary file is cleaned up afterward and has reasonably secure permissions, but these could be security concerns.

```
$ ls -l /tmp/z*
-rw------- 1 user user 1640882 Mar 23 06:26 /tmp/zathura.stdin.97PFXY
```

It's available in the standard repositories on Arch, Debian and Ubuntu.